# How do I find the package that contains a given program on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, aptitude, apt

Frequently I know the name of the command line program that I need but I don't know the name of the package that provides the program. How do I find the name of the package that contains the program that I need? On RPM based systems they have the `whatprovides` option `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/X11R6/bin/xclock` which will find the correct package. Is there anything similar for Debian based systems?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the package is installed, you want `dpkg -S /path/to/file`.  If the package isn't installed, then use the apt-file utility (`apt-file update; apt-file search /path/to/file`).

Comment: +1 You can use dlocate instead of dpkg -S to make the searching almost instantaneous, but you need to install it. http://packages.ubuntu.com can also be used instead of apt-file if you want to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 11):

Ubuntu has a command-not-found utility which will tell you which package to install to get a specific command. If configured correctly (perhaps in the default install?) it will show up when you enter a command that isn't installed. However, you can also run it manually:

```
$ /usr/lib/command-not-found --ignore-installed test
The program 'test' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install coreutils
```

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu, as does Debian, comes with the apt-file application. This allows you, quite similar to apt-get, to just search for files in packages.

Thus, you'd have

```
$ apt-file update
$ apt-file search xclock
```

And there you go. If you're lucky, you can also use the interface at the bottom of the [Debian packages](http://packages.debian.org/) site. This will work if the Ubuntu maintainers haven't changed that much compared to the original Debian version.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apt-cache search [file] to check the local caches for the app.

Comment: dpkg -S /usr/bin/reduce-font => libbogl-dev; apt-cache search reduce-font and apt-cache search /usr/bin/reduce-font both return nothing.  Care to expand your answer?

Comment: womble, I do not know what goes wrong at your end, but for me what Tim Howland suggests works "apt-cache search xprop" and "apt-cache search remmina".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nala (frontend over apt).
nala search "application name". Nala will return package names.

[Nala Search](https://linuxlifehacks.com/nala-beautiful-apt-frontend-for-ubuntu)